# Substitution of characters limited to part of each input line

Tags: sed, substitution, string-substitution

Have a file eg. Inventory.conf with lines like:

```
Int/domain—home.dir=/etc/int
```

I need to replace `/` and `—` before the `=` but not after.
Result should be:

```
Int_domain_home_dir=/etc/int
```

I have tried several `sed` commands but none seem to fit my need.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed with a `t` loop (BRE):

```
$ sed ':a;s/[-/—.]\(.*=\)/_\1/;ta;' <<< "Int/domain—home.dir=/etc/int"
Int_domain_home_dir=/etc/int
```

When one of the `-/—.` character is found, it's replaced with a `_`. Following text up to `=` is captured and output using backreference. If the previous substitution succeeds, the `t` command loops to label  `:a`  to check for further replacements.

**Edit:**

If you're under BSD/Mac OSX (thanks @mklement0):

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's/[-/—.]\(.*=\)/_\1/;ta'
```

Comment: Thanks - you guys are amazing!

Comment: While this is a clever way to simulate field-based processing in `sed`, it's also a slow one, due to using a line-internal loop, which may matter with large input sets.
To make this GNU `sed` command work with BSD/macOS `sed`, use `sed -e ':a' -e 's/[-/—.]\(.*=\)/_\1/;ta'`.

Comment: @mklement0 You're right, but I'm not sure the OP needs performance with a conf file. He's probably more interested in a syntax he is familiar with.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the BSD syntax, I edited my answer.

Comment: @Kenavoz: Thanks for updating your answer. Clearly, your answer worked for the OP, and that's great, but future readers may have differing requirements, which is why I added my performance note.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for a `sed` solution, but **an `awk` solution is simpler and performs better in this case**, because you can easily split the line into 2 fields by `=` and then selectively apply `gsub()` to only the 1st field in order to replace the characters of interest:

```
$ awk -F= '{ gsub("[./-]", "_", $1); print $1 FS $2 }' <<< 'Int/domain-home.dir=/etc/int'
Int_domain_home_dir=/etc/int
```

- `-F=` tells `awk` to split the input into fields by `=`, which with the input at hand results in `$1` (1st field) containing the first half of the line, before the `=`, and `$2` (2nd field) the 2nd half, after the `=`; using the `-F` option sets variable `FS`, the input field separator.
- `gsub("[./-]", "_", $1)` globally replaces all characters in set `[./-]` with `_` in `$1` - i.e., all occurrences of either `.`, `/` or `-` in the 1st field are replaced with a `_` each.
- `print $1 FS $2` prints the result: the modified 1st field (`$1`), followed by `FS` (which is `=`), followed by the (unmodified) 2nd field (`$2`).

Note that I've used ASCII char. `-` (*HYPHEN-MINUS*, codepoint `0x2d`) in the `awk` script, even though your sample input contains the Unicode char. `—` (*EM DASH*, `U+2014`, UTF-8 encoding `0xe2 0x80 0x94`).
If you really want to match *that*, simply substitute it in the command above, but note that the `awk` version on macOS won't handle that properly.

Another option is to use `iconv` with ASCII transliteration, which tranlates the em dash into a regular ASCII `-`:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit <<< 'Int/domain—home.dir=/etc/int' |
  awk -F= '{ gsub("[./-]", "_", $1); print $1 FS $2 }'
```

---

**`perl`** allows for an elegant solution too:

```
$ perl -F= -ane '$F[0] =~ tr|-/.|_|; print join("=", @F)' <<<'Int/domain-home.dir=/etc/int'
Int_domain_home_dir=/etc/int
```

- `-F=`, just like with Awk, tells Perl to use `=` as the separator when splitting lines into fields
- `-ane` activates field splitting (`a`), turns off implicit output (`n`), and `e` tells Perl that the *next* argument is an expression (command string) to execute.
- The fields that each line is split into is stored in array `@F`, where `$F[0]` refers to the 1st field.
- `$F[0] =~ tr|-/.|-|` translates (replaces) all occurrences of `-`, `/`, and `.` to `_`.
- `print join("=", @F)` rebuilds the input line from the fields - with the 1st field now modified - and prints the result.

Depending on the Awk implementation used, this may actually be faster (see below).

---

That `sed` isn't the best tool for this job is also reflected in the **relative performance** of the solutions:

Sample timings from my macOS 10.12 machine (GNU `sed` 4.2.2, Mawk `awk` 1.3.4, `perl` v5.18.2, using input file `file`, which contains 1 million copies of the sample input line) - take them with a grain of salt, but the *ratios* of the numbers are of interest; fastest solutions first:

```
# This answer's awk answer.
# Note: Mawk is much faster here than GNU Awk and BSD Awk.
$ time awk -F= '{ gsub("[./-]", "_", $1); print $1 FS $2 }' file >/dev/null
real    0m0.657s

# This answer's perl solution:
# Note: On macOS, this outperforms the Awk solution when using either
#       GNU Awk or BSD Awk.
$ time perl -F= -ane '$F[0] =~ tr|-/.|_|; print join("=", @F)' file >/dev/null
real    0m1.656s

# Sundeep's perl solution with tr///
$ time perl -pe 's#^[^=]+#$&=~tr|/.-|_|r#e' file >/dev/null
real    0m2.370s

# Sundeep's perl solution with s///
$ time perl -pe 's#^[^=]+#$&=~s|[/.-]|_|gr#e' file >/dev/null
real    0m3.540s

# Cyrus' solution.
$ time sed 'h;s/[^=]*//;x;s/=.*//;s/[/.-]/_/g;G;s/\n//' file >/dev/null
real    0m4.090s

# Kenavoz' solution.
# Note: The 3-byte UTF-8 em dash is NOT included in the char. set,
#       for consistency of comparison with the other solutions.
#       Interestingly, adding the em dash adds another 2 seconds or so.
$ time sed ':a;s/[-/.]\(.*=\)/_\1/;ta' file >/dev/null
real    0m9.036s
```

As you can see, the `awk` solution is fastest by far, with the line-internal-loop `sed` solution predictably performing worst, by a factor of about 12.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
echo 'Int/domain—home.dir=/etc/int' | sed 'h;s/[^=]*//;x;s/=.*//;s/[/—.]/_/g;G;s/\n//'
```

Output:

```
Int_domain_home_dir=/etc/int
```

See: `man sed`. I assume you want to replace  dots too.

Comment: tnx for example. It however did not substitute the "-".
I have made a test.txt with only one line:
sed "h;s/[^=]*//;x;s/=.*//;s/[—./]/_/g;G;s/\n//" test.txt
this-is-_a_test=indeed-it/is.just-that

Comment: Please disregard that first comment :-)
Below is my comment:

tnx for example. It however did not substitute the "-" please see below:
I have made a test.txt with only one line:
  cat test.txt 
  this-is/a.test=indeed-it/is.just-that

Result:
  sed "h;s/[^=]*//;x;s/=.*//;s/[—./]/_/g;G;s/\n//" test.txt
  this-is_a_test=indeed-it/is.just-that

Why that "-" is not substituted is beyond me :-(

Comment: @HoneyBee, in your question, you have used `—` which is called emdash I think... it is different from `-`

Answer (score 1):

If `perl` solution is okay:

```
$ echo 'Int/domain-home.dir=/etc/int' | perl -pe 's#^[^=]+#$&=~s|[/.-]|_|gr#e'
Int_domain_home_dir=/etc/int
```

- `^[^=]+` string matching from start of line up to but not including the first occurrence of `=`
- `$&=~s|[/.-]|_|gr` perform another substitution on matched string

  - replace all `/` or `.` or `-` characters with `_`
  - the `r` modifier would return the modified string
- the `e` modifier allows to use expression instead of string in replacement section
- `#` is used as delimiter to avoid having to escape `/` inside the character class `[/.-]`

Also, as suggested by @mklement0, we can use translate instead of inner substitute

```
$ echo 'Int/domain-home.dir=/etc/int' | perl -pe 's#^[^=]+#$&=~tr|/.-|_|r#e'
Int_domain_home_dir=/etc/int
```

Note that I've changed sample input, `-` is used instead of `—` which is what OP seems to want based on comments

Comment: ++ for advanced Perl techniques, but, truthfully, even with the explanation it might be difficult to understand. Ever-so-slight simplification: `perl -pe 's/^[^=]+/$&=~tr|\/.-|_|r/e'`

Comment: @mklement0, thanks.. added the `tr` alternate to answer... personally, I've found `perl` to work very well for most cases, combining best of `sed`, `awk` and more, plus its regex has more options like lookarounds, skip, etc.. and compared to various `sed` and `awk` version differences, using `perl` might be easier for portability

Comment: Agreed in general - Perl is really powerful, and unless you're bitten by version differences, portable. But its syntax is arcane, and startup cost of the interpreter is non-trivial; depending on your use case, a good old `sed` and `awk` solution may be faster and sometimes also simpler (though you do have to be aware of platform differences there).