# Replacement within the matched string with sed

Tags: regex, linux, replace, sed

I have a property file for java like below.

```
server.port=8080
spring.application.name=app1
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I want to convert the file to a linux equivalent property file like below.

```
SERVER_PORT=8080
SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=app1
SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=org.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I am using `sed`, and I am able to convert the property names with the following sed command.

```
sed "s/^\(.*\)=\(.*\)$/\U\1=\E\2/" application.properties
```

However, I am not able to figure out how to replace the dots(`.`) with underscore(`_`) character in the matched part(`\1`).

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `perl` is okay:

```
$ perl -pe 's/^.*=/\U$&/; s/^.*=/$&=~s|\.|_|gr/e' application.properties 
SERVER_PORT=8080
SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=app1
SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME=org.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

- `s/^.*=/$&=~s|\.|_|gr/e` use another substitution for captured text `^.*=`

Can be simplified to

```
$ perl -pe 's/^.*=/uc $&=~s|\.|_|gr/e' application.properties 
SERVER_PORT=8080
SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=app1
SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME=org.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

With `sed`

```
$ sed 's/^.*=/\U&/; :a s/^\([^=]*\)\./\1_/g; ta' application.properties 
SERVER_PORT=8080
SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=app1
SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME=org.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

- `:a s/^\([^=]*\)\./\1_/g; ta` replace `.` with `_` until the text before `.` doesn't contain `=`

If both `.` and `-` before `=` needs to be changed to `_`, use `[.-]` instead of `\.` in both solutions

Answer (score 2):

You can use a conditional loop:

```
sed 's/^[^=]*/\U&/;:a;s/^\([^=]*\)[.-]/\1_/;ta'
```

Where `ta` jumps to the label "a" as long as something is replaced.

With awk:

```
awk -F= -vOFS='=' '{$1=toupper($1);gsub("[-.]", "_", $1)}1'
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative `perl` solution that is perhaps conceptually simpler: <sup>Tip of the hat to [@Sundeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082052/sundeep) for his help with simplifying the command.</sup>

```
perl -F'(=)' -ane '$F[0] = uc $F[0] =~ tr/./_/r; print @F' application.properties
```

- `-F(=)`, combined with `-a`, splits each input line into fields by `=`. (`-n` suppresses default output, and `-e` tells Perl to treat the next operand as a *command*).
  Enclosing `=`  in `(...)` also makes the `=` instances part of the field array stored in `@F`.
- `$F[0] =~ tr/./_/r` translates all literal `.` chars. into `_` chars. in the 1st field (the property name) and returns the result, thanks to the `r` option.
- `$F[0] = uc` then converts the result to all-uppercase and updates the 1st field with the result.
- `print @F` then prints all fields, starting with the modified 1st field, separated by `=` (the output field separators that were also captured in `@F`), in effect printing the upper-cased 1st input field with `.` chars. translated to `_`, followed by `=` and the unmodified remainder of the input line.

Comment: good one, can also use `perl -F'/(=)/' -ane '$F[0] =~ tr/./_/; $F[0] = uc $F[0]; print @F'`

Comment: also, using `r` modifier --> `$F[0] = uc $F[0] =~ tr/./_/r`

Comment: `$,` by default has no character separation defined, isn't it? check out `perl -le '@a = (1, "abc", 5); print @a'` vs `perl -le '@a = (1, "abc", 5); print "@a"'` and `perl -le '@a = (1, "abc", 5); $,=":"; print @a'`

Comment: `-F'(=)'` means the separation character `=` is also saved in `@F` array... check `perl -F'(=)' -lane 'print $F[1]'` vs `perl -F'=' -lane 'print $F[1]'`

Comment: @Sundeep: Got it; I had a misconception about what using a capture group with `-F` does; corrected now. And to answer my own question: that capture groups used with `-F` add the separators to the fields array is described in the help topic for the [`split` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.24.0/functions/split.html)

Comment: @Sundeep: As a minor point of interest: Using the capture-group-in-field-separator approach is conceptually _simpler_, but seemingly _slower_ in terms of execution: when I tried it as an alternative solution with the benchmarks in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40414542/45375) of mine, it was noticeably slower (though that will only matter with large input sets).

Comment: probably because `print @F` would still need a loop and use `$,` which we were doing similar with join anyway.. but incurring extra penalty for capturing the separator..

Answer (score 2):

With `cut`, `tr`, `paste` and process substitution (requires Bash):

```
$ paste -d= <(cut -f1 -d= application.properties | tr '[:lower:].-' '[:upper:]_') \
>           <(cut -f2 -d= application.properties)
SERVER_PORT=8080
SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=app1
SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=org.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Both `cut` and `paste` use `=` as the delimiter, and the first `cut` pipes to `tr` for uppercasing and replacing periods and dashes with underscores.

Comment: ++ for conceptual simplicity, even though multiple child processes are involved (probably won't matter in this case).